Problem to debug powershell script in Visual Studio Code
I like to debug a simple "Hello World" powershell script but it does not work.
When I click on the "Debug" Icon (or press F5) then nothing happens. I only get some waiting (hourglass cursor) symbols.


This waiting symbol disappears after a few seconds:

but no output nor warning/error or anything else. This bar  does not appear either.
Here are the relevant configuration settings:
"launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "name": "PowerShell Launch Current File",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "script": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${cwd}"
        }
    ]
},

{
"[powershell]": {
    "debug.saveBeforeStart": "nonUntitledEditorsInActiveGroup",
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
    "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
},
"powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "Windows PowerShell",
"powershell.integratedConsole.suppressStartupBanner": true,
"powershell.codeFormatting.useCorrectCasing": true,
"powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths": {
    "Powershell 7.4": "c:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
    "Powershell 7.4 (x86)": "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
    "Windows PowerShell (x86)": "C:\\Windows\\syswow64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "Windows PowerShell": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
},
"powershell.enableProfileLoading": false,
"powershell.developer.setExecutionPolicy": true,
"powershell.promptToUpdatePowerShell": false,
"powershell.scriptAnalysis.enable": false
}

When I check powershell processes in task manager, then I see three of these:

C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command "try { . "c:\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\common\scripts\shellIntegration.ps1" } catch {}"

and one of this:

C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Import-Module 'c:\Users\domscheit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2024.2.2\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\PowerShellEditorServices.psd1'; Start-EditorServices -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2024.2.2' -BundledModulesPath 'c:\Users\domscheit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2024.2.2\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -StartupBanner '' -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'c:\Users\domscheit\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\logs\1730459834-91263a09-72a8-4d3d-ba7b-4a660827ecc61730459830802' -SessionDetailsPath 'c:\Users\domscheit\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\sessions\PSES-VSCode-30532-239919.json' -FeatureFlags @() "

Any idea to get it working? I check several existing questions, but none of them solved my issue.

I assume, I found the problem. The Powershell extension is blocked by AppLocker. I found this in the Event Logs:

%OSDRIVE%\USERS\DOMSCHEIT.VSCODE\EXTENSIONS\MS-VSCODE.POWERSHELL-2024.2.2\MODULES\POWERSHELLEDITORSERVICES\COMMANDS\POWERSHELLEDITORSERVICES.COMMANDS.TYPES.PS1XML was prevented from running.


Settings: The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: , C:\Users\domscheit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2024.2.2\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\Commands\PowerShellEditorServices.Commands.types.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: File C:\Users\domscheit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2024.2.2\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\Commands\PowerShellEditorServices.Commands.types.ps1xml cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy..

Looks like I have to talk to our IT Security guys.
